# variable content is different than the output of the assigned command

Tags: variable, echo

I'm having a problem when trying to echo a variable. The echo output of the variable is different than the output of the command. Why any thing like this happen?
I suppose it may have something to do with the text, since this problem didn't appear when applying this on a different text.

```
me@myPC:~/some/directory/$ grep "frag" link | awk '{print$2}'
KETENE
OH
H2O
HCCO
CO
CH2OH
H
CH(OH)CO
(HCO)2
HCO
CH2O
CH3O
CO2
CH3
me@myPC:~/some/directory/$ frag_list=$(grep "frag" link | awk '{print$2}')
me@myPC:~/some/directory/$ echo $frag_list 
 CH3O)2CO
```

Comment: This is a multi-line output string and so what happens when you echo "$frag_list"

Comment: And [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: And your file probably has CRLF line-delimiters as opposed to normal LF ones.

Comment: Here, you probably want `frag_list=$(dos2unix < link | awk '/frag/{print $2}'); printf '%s\n' "$frag_list"`

Answer (score 0):

```
frag_list=`cat link | grep "frag" | awk '{print$2}'`
```

should do it